# center text over arrow in a diagram

Tags: commutative-diagrams

I have this diagram, but `a` and `c` are not over the center of arrow and I want `a` and `c` over the center of arrow. How can I do it?

```
\xymatrix{X \ar[r]^{a} \ar@/_2pc/[rr]_{b}  & Y \ar[r]^{c} & Z}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason we ask for a MWE is because most of the time a snippet does not illustrate a problem so compiling your lines as follows:-

```
\documentclass{standalone}\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,xypic}\begin{document}
    \xymatrix{X \ar[r]^{a} \ar@/_2pc/[rr]_{b}  & Y \ar[r]^{c} & Z}
  % \xymatrix{F(H) \ar[r]^\pi \ar@/_2pc/[rr]_{i} & {\Inv(B(H)/K(H))} \ar[r]^{\gamma} & {\Lambda_{B(H)/K(H)}}}
    \xymatrix{F(H) \ar[r]^{\kern-10pt{\pi}} \ar@/_2pc/[rr]_{i} & {\dfrac{B(H)}{K(H)}^{-1}}\ar[r]^{\gamma} & {\lambda_{\dfrac{B(H)}{K(H)}}}}
\end{document}
```

I feel this is the answer since `a` and `c` appear to be centred on their arrows ?

The second example shows the problem better since there is less space for the arrows (a shortcoming with this type of construct) however by resorting to fractions and some minimal kerning I can generate this.

[image]

Comment: because, is an example, for me i use $\[
\xymatrix{F(H) \ar[r]^\pi \ar@/_2pc/[rr]_{i}  & {\Inv(B(H)/K(H))} \ar[r]^{\gamma} & {\Lambda_{B(H)/K(H)}}}
\]$  but is not center $\pi$ and $\gamma$, show over the peak of arrow

Comment: thanks i dont know about \kern